# How to merge two branches(master and demo branch) code in Git

Tags: android, git

I've 2 branches,like master and demo.
I want to merge demo code in to master so please help me to solve this issue.
Branches
1 Master
2 demo

Comment: So what's the point? Just merge and solve the conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

`git checkout Master`

`git merge demo`

resolve conflicts, assuming all branches are up to date and local

(Will add more detail, just to be complete, if you are using online repo)

`git checkout demo`

`git pull` (now demo is updated locally)

`git checkout Master`

`git pull` (now Master is updated locally)

`git merge demo`

resolve any conflicts, which can be done through android studio as well, VCS -> Git -> Resolve Conflicts

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming two branches master and demo.Merge Master code to demo

Step 1
  A.go to the master->git checkout Master. 
  B.pull all the new changes from Master branch.

Step 2
  A. now got to demo branch->git checkout demo

Step 3
 A.merge the changes of Master branch into Demo branch git merge Master
 B.Then push your updated code to git git push origin demo.